# Is there a better way than parsing /proc/self/maps to figure out memory protection?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, mprotect, virtualquery

On Linux (or Solaris) is there a better way than hand parsing `/proc/self/maps` repeatedly to figure out whether or not you can read, write or execute whatever is stored at one or more addresses in memory?

For instance, in Windows you have `VirtualQuery`.

In Linux, I can `mprotect` to change those values, but I can't read them back.

Furthermore, is there any way to know when those permissions change (e.g. when someone uses `mmap` on a file behind my back) other than doing something terribly invasive and using `ptrace` on all threads in the process and intercepting any attempt to make a `syscall` that could affect the memory map?

**Update:**

Unfortunately, I'm using this inside of a JIT that has very little information about the code it is executing to get an approximation of what is constant. Yes, I realize I could have a constant map of mutable data, like the vsyscall page used by Linux. I *can* safely fall back on an assumption that anything that isn't included in the initial parse is mutable and dangerous, but I'm not entirely happy with that option.

Right now what I do is I read `/proc/self/maps` and build a structure I can binary search through for a given address's protection. Any time I need to know something about a page that isn't in my structure I reread /proc/self/maps assuming it has been added in the meantime or I'd be about to segfault anyways.

It just seems that parsing text to get at this information and not knowing when it changes is awfully crufty. (`/dev/inotify` doesn't work on pretty much anything in `/proc`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not know an equivalent of `VirtualQuery` on Linux. But some other ways to do it which may or may not work are:

- you setup a signal handler trapping SIGBUS/SIGSEGV and go ahead with your read or write. If the memory is protected, your signal trapping code will be called. If not your signal trapping code is not called. Either way you win.
- you could track each time you call `mprotect` and build a corresponding data structure which helps you in knowing if a region is read or write protected. This is good if you have access to all the code which uses `mprotect`.
- you can monitor all the `mprotect` calls in your process by linking your code with a library redefining the function `mprotect`. You can then build the necessary data structure for knowing if a region is read or write protected and then call the system `mprotect` for really setting the protection.
- you may try to use `/dev/inotify` and monitor the file `/proc/self/maps` for any change. I guess this one does not work, but should be worth the try.

Comment: By the time I get a SIGSEGV its too late. I need to know if some data is constant to know that I can "safely" constant fold through it. With appropriate hacks for constant mmap'ed non-constant data and the vsyscall page.

Answer (score 0):

There sorta is/was /proc/[pid|self]/pagemap, documentation in the kernel, caveats here:
https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/7/14/477
So it isn't completely harmless...