# Can I write-protect every page in the address space of a Linux process?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, signal-handling, mprotect

I'm wondering if there's a way to write-protect every page in a Linux
process' address space (from inside of the process itself, by way of
`mprotect()`).  By "every page", I really mean every page of the
process's address space that might be written to by an ordinary
program running in user mode -- so, the program text, the constants,
the globals, and the heap -- but I would be happy with just constants,
globals, and heap.  I don't want to write-protect the stack -- that
seems like a bad idea.

One problem is that I don't know where to start write-protecting
memory.  Looking at `/proc/pid/maps`, which shows the sections of memory
in use for a given pid, they always seem to start with the address
`0x08048000`, with the program text.  (In Linux, as far as I can tell,
the memory of a process is laid out with the program text at the
bottom, then constants above that, then globals, then the heap, then
an empty space of varying size depending on the size of the heap or
stack, and then the stack growing down from the top of memory at
virtual address `0xffffffff`.)  There's a way to tell where the top of
the heap is (by calling `sbrk(0)`, which simply returns a pointer to the
current "break", i.e., the top of the heap), but not really a way to
tell where the heap begins.

If I try to protect all pages from `0x08048000` up to the break, I 
eventually get an `mprotect: Cannot allocate memory` error.  I don't know why `mprotect` would be 
allocating memory anyway -- and Google is not very helpful.  Any ideas?

By the way, the reason I want to do this is because I want to create a
list of all pages that are written to during a run of the program, and
the way that I can think of to do this is to write-protect all pages,
let any attempted writes cause a write fault, then implement a write
fault handler that will add the page to the list and then remove the write
protection.  I think I know how to implement the handler, if only I could
figure out which pages to protect and how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: I actually already have code that does exactly what you're trying to do.  Your idea will work, but you cannot protect the pages on which your "these-pages-were-written" lists will reside, or your SEGV handler will cause a SEGV!

Comment: @Borealid, thanks, and that's now the problem that I'm trying to solve (I've got the segfault handler and the /proc/self/maps parsing working now).  How to avoid protecting the page(s) that contain that list?  Allocating the list on the stack would work, but then I don't see any way to pass it to the handler.  Alternatively, I could allocate it as a global, but I'd like to use a fancier data structure than a fixed-length array (like an STL container), and I might not always know where the list I'm writing to is located in memory.

Comment: @borealid: You said that you have code that does exactly this--would you mind sharing your code? I'm new here, and I couldn't find a way to contact you (back-channel) directly. I am trying to do exactly what Linsey is doing, so any code samples would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You recieve `ENOMEM` from `mprotect()` if you try to call it on pages that aren't mapped.

Your best bet is to open `/proc/self/maps`, and read it a line at a time with `fgets()` to find all the mappings in your process.  For each writeable mapping (indicated in the second field) that isn't the stack (indicated in the last field), call `mprotect()` with the right base address and length (calculated from the start and end addresses in the first field).

Note that you'll need to have your fault handler already set up at this point, because the act of reading the `maps` file itself will likely cause writes within your address space.

Comment: Thanks -- I was hoping that there would be some way around having to hand-parse /proc/self/maps, but it appears that there isn't (from the discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269314/is-there-a-better-way-than-parsing-proc-self-maps-to-figure-out-memory-protectio).

Answer (score 0):

Start simple. Write-protect a few page and make sure your signal handler works for these pages. Then worry about expanding the scope of the protection. For example, you probably do not need to write-protect the code-section: operating systems can implement write-or-execute protection semantics on memory that will prevent code sections from ever being written to:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code#Operating_systems

Comment: Yeah, for this problem we can assume no self-modifying code for now.  I'd be OK with either write-protecting the code section or not, whichever is easier.

Comment: Actually what I was trying to say is that your code sections are most likely already write-protected.