# how to get the memory access type in C/C++ in Linux

Tags: c, linux, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a better way than parsing /proc/self/maps to figure out memory protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269314/is-there-a-better-way-than-parsing-proc-self-maps-to-figure-out-memory-protecti)

I have a pointer and I want to check if the referenced memory is readable, writeable and/or executable. How can I do this?

Comment: I am voting to close, as any answers to this question are either in the other question or are valid answers to the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to parse the file `/proc/self/maps` which contains memory mappings of your process, and check which of the mappings lie within the value of your pointer (if any). The `/proc/self/maps` file contains the memory protection (read/write/execute).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-id-maps) for more info about the maps file.