# Is there a Linux API for gathering information about mmap'ed regions?

Tags: linux, mmap

I know I can read the file `/proc/$PID/maps`, but I was wondering if there is an API to get process memory mappings.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269314/is-there-a-better-way-than-parsing-proc-self-maps-to-figure-out-memory-protectio - it is rather similar

Comment: For this problem I actually made a kernel module that would walk the processes vma in kernel space.  Parsing even a simple /proc/*/maps takes about 70us... grrr.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API in kernel to get this information in 1 syscall. The only universal way is to read and parse a `/proc/self/maps` file.